# Async Await function not awaiting

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, bcrypt

I'm trying to hash a password before adding it to a database, but my async hash function isn't allowed to finish before attempting to add to my database.

calling the await function:

```
const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(newPassword)
console.log({ hashedPassword })
```

console.log({hashedPassword}) returns undefined

hashPassword function:

```
const hashPassword = async (password) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(422).send({ error: err.message })
        }
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(422).send({ error: err.message })
            }
            console.log({hash})        
            return hash
        })
    })
}
```

console.log({hash}) returns a hashed password (as expected).

Comment: You are using a callback function within an async function. Furthermore your return statement only returns a value for  the callback, not for the actual function hashPassword. You should check if bcrypt already has the possibility to use promises instead of callback functions. Alternatively, you can use a module called promisify to transform the genSalt function into a promise-returning function on the fly. This will simplify your code.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for your help, I didn't realize calling a callback function within an async function would be an issue. bcrypt did have a promise ability, which fixed the issue. Thanks for your help